# How to get values from web.config app key to a list

Tags: c#

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<add key="someValuestoReturn" value="60,59,58,57,56"/>
```

I want to return a list of this integer values into my my method but i'm having a difficult to call the list of the values from the web.config:

```
    Private int GetValues(){

    var _list = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someValuestoReturn"].ToList();  //<< doesn't work

return _list
    }
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: The values are comma separated; read in the string and split on the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest you to solve this on another way..

lets first create an a empty list of a strings which we are going later to put into an array:

After that we need to find your key and we need to get values from a key into our new created list, but we must take care about spliting because your values are comma separated, so check my code below:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();

foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith("someValuestoReturn"))
            {
                string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].Split(',');
                values.Add(value);
            }

        }

string[] myValuesfromWebConfig = values.ToArray();
```

And that's it, you get all of your values stored in a array called `myValuesfromWebConfig`

And if you want something else than a string, just change your list/array type from `string` to `int` for example..

As you can see I included

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].Split(',');
```

[HERE MORE ABOUT Split method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

because your values are comma separated, and I guess you would like to add them to a array/list separately.. :)

Thanks

EDIT:

Because of your error that you wrote in comment, we can skip adding it to an a array, simply delete that line, you will have your values stored in list `values` anyway, so at the end it migth look like this:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();

foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
{
     if (key.StartsWith("someValuestoReturn"))
     {
                    string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].Split(',');
                    values.Add(value);
     }

}
```

Now if you need to read that values or do whatever you want with them, you can loop throught them and that's it, for example:

```
foreach(var item in values)
{
  //Do whatever you want with your item
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks.. i'm getting the following error: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'string[]'

any idea to why this is?

Comment: @1future on what line actually ? Probably here : string[] myValuesfromWebConfig = values.ToArray();  check for my EDIT

Comment: @1future if this answer was helpful to you please accept it and vote it up :) thanks

Comment: on this line : string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].Split(',');

Comment: @1future if this answer was helpful to you please vote it up :)

Answer (score 0):

A string is returned not a `List`.

For a `List` use:

```
var _list = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someValuestoReturn"].Split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someValuestoReturn"].Split(',');
```

it will return a string array